# how to remove single quotes (‘) of string in php

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

How to remove starting and ending closing single quotes in php

```
‘/home/abhisheksrivastav/deploy/file_uploaded/listmaster-exportfile/363-00.csv’
```

NOTE: here single quotes is something different from Normal single quote typed using keyboard.

Comment: From where do you getting this string, Your question is not clear enough. Please specify what you want to do and why do you want to do it?

Comment: @Dinidu, I received this from split command output, Although I think trim and str_replace would be enough , thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function for that.

```
$a = '‘/home/abhisheksrivastav/deploy/file_uploaded/listmaster-exportfile/363-00.csv’';
echo trim($a, '‘’');
```

Comment: That won't get the ending one, will it?

Comment: @ClasG ups... sorry. Updated answer :-)